# What happened to Dolores Umbridge after the end of Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

What happened to Dolores Umbridge after the end of Deathly Hallows? Was she punished?

Comment: She was executed. *"Death to Traitors!!!" yelled Hermione as she lifted the axe.*

Comment: @Valorum You never fail to make me grin. I dont care if it never happened, thats amazing

Comment: @AlexSpencer - It was from the version of the novel her editor rejected. The one where Harry and Ginny [got freaky-deaky](http://favim.com/orig/201106/09/by-book-he-means-penis-cute-ginny-weasley-harry-potter-love-Favim.com-69690.jpg)

Comment: @Valorum ahh yes, the R rated one. Where everyones a nutcase. To be fair, if i wanted that I'd watch game of thrones. on that note...

Comment: This is answered in another very similar question.