# What happened to Barty Crouch Jr. after he was given the Dementor's Kiss?

Tags: harry-potter

At the end of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* we see for the first time an actual **Dementor's Kiss** given to Barty Crouch Jr.

We know by fact that a Dementor's Kiss doesn't actually kill the person to whom it is given; it just takes away his soul, leaving him soulless but still alive.

**What was the fate of Barty Crouch Jr. after he was given the Dementor's Kiss?**

Comment: He was executed. *"Death to Traitors!!!" yelled Hermione as she lifted the axe [for a second time](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133150/what-happened-to-dolores-umbridge-after-the-end-of-deathly-hallows#comment335772_133150)"*

Comment: @Valorum hahaha u rumbling all around xD but you just gave me another idea of a great question :D    ....... edit: ohhhh man.... the princess got me again long before.... http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/what-effect-would-the-dementors-kiss-have-on-voldemort-prior-to-the-destruction

Comment: @Valorum jeeze, do you just have a box of repeated comments to spray down here about harry potter? second time ive seen this one TODAY :P

Comment: @AlexSpencer - Ah, but this one was *subtly different*, that being the joke.  Since the question was similar, my comment was similar, except that I [called-back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(comedy)) to the earlier comment to create humour.

Comment: @Valorum "for a second time" I see now. I'm slow sorry XD     Is there like a watch person button or something, i could just spy on your comments here all day

Comment: @AlexSpencer - Yes. If you go to someone's profile, then to the activity tab, then comments, you can see pretty much everything they're doing apart from voting; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: @Valorum totally didnt just do that to spy on more harry potter stuff in the slightest. totally *shifty eyes*

Comment: He became an ex-wizard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### It is not revealed

The last time Barty Crouch Jr. is mentioned is in *Goblet of Fire*, where his soul is sucked out by Ministry Dementors, as mentioned in the question. **To the best of my knowledge, his fate has never been mentioned again in any official, canonical, or licensed Harry Potter work.** He merits a passing line in *Order of the Phoenix* (mentioning past events only), and that is about all.

It seems most likely, though, that his body would have been taken to St. Mungo's Hospital and kept on whatever the wizard equivalent of life support is. He would not have had anyone to say otherwise, regardless of his preference. Of course, it is possible that standard policy in the wizarding world is not to keep victims of the Kiss on life support, particularly if they are convicted mass murderers, so even this is uncertain.

**Ultimately, we simply do not know.**
In the end, though, whether Crouch Jr. is technically alive or not, he is effectively dead for all plot purposes.

Comment: Would he need life support? My impression was that Dementor's Kiss victims lost all sense of self, will, desire, etc, but had no problems with being physically alive. Unless you mean someone to feed him?

Comment: @MissMonicaE - Basically, yes. I don't think he'd be able to eat of his own volition after being Kissed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think he could have started a new life somehow because once you get kissed by a Dementor you cannot live like a functioning, ration person.

> "You can exist without your soul, you know, as long as your brain and heart are still working. But you'll have no sense of self anymore, no memory, no...anything. **There's no chance at all of recovery.** You'll just — exist. As an empty shell. And your soul is gone forever... lost."
>   —Remus Lupin (Prisoner of Azkaban)

But according to Harrypotter.wiki (http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dementor%27s_Kiss) its not been made clear as to what happens to the soul once its sucked by Dementors.

Answer (score 0):

I have wondered about this myself. It seems a person is able to live without a soul, but it's left to debate how. In Professor Snape's classroom, when he is the DADA teacher, there is a picture of a victim of the Dementor's Kiss, showing the person just sitting, hollow. It seems there may be a similarity between imprisonment in Azkaban and suffering the Kiss, although, upon release, the prisoners seem to come back to themselves..whereas there is no returning the soul back once the Demetors have taken it...leading to further questions..where does the kissed soul go..and a connection to Horcruxes, but a maimed and split soul by dark magic can be made whole again by remorse, but the pain can kill you, however yoir soul is once again whole and able to 'move on'...very interesting subject..possibly, Rowling left this open on purpose :)

Comment: Can you make it more clear what this is answering? Answers should answer the question, even if by speculating.

Comment: Im sorry, your right..i let my thoughts wander..i was speculating about Barty Crouch Jr, and what might have happened to him

Comment: You can edit it to give an answer.

Comment: The question is on top of this page..i had searched the internet as to what might have happened to him, and it brought me here

Comment: There is no clear answer

Comment: Could you make that point more clear in your answer?